# A theory or concept related to language use by elite or the higher classes

Tags: linguistics, concept

I'm an English teacher, and I'm looking for a theoretical model that suggests language is used differently by different classes. I am aware of Bernstein's Elaborated code, which refers to an elite using an exclusive sociolect, but I think this just refers to spoken language. Is there anything similar?

Comment: '[Sociolects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolect) involve both passive acquisition of particular communicative practices through association with a local community, as well as active learning and choice among speech **or writing forms** to demonstrate identification with particular groups.'

Comment: **All** theoretical models refer to spoken language. Spoken language is the real language, whereas writing is merely a technology for recording spoken language.

Comment: @John Lawler :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler I suggest on the contrary that the written and spoken languages are distinct linguistic media, dialects as distinct as jazz and classical music, each bound to distinct pragmatic principles, each capable of distinctive effects the other cannot achieve--and each enriched from time to time with innovations arising in the other.

Comment: @StoneyB I like it. But, of course, the whole thing is _largely_ driven by the spoken language, as that is far more commonly used, and writing forms do tend to play catch-up. Where they can. But non-verbal language is also an important factor in face-to-face communications. Also, new philosophical and mathematical etc theories may need new language, which is probably first committed to paper or disk. There's the overall -life-informs-language-informs-life- spiral.

Comment: There's the overall -life-informs-language-informs-life- spiral. –  Edwin Ashworth I wonder if there is a theoretical principle for that!

Comment: @StoneyB: I would not make that analogy. There is a more direct analogue involving playing vs. written music. The symbols and staves used to write music down aren't really the music themselves; at most they are a guideline. Even the strictest interpretations of classical pieces involve deviation from the bare notes, else it would sound very boring.

Comment: @Robusto Quite so; but the great distinction is not that between the score and the performance but the entirely different character of performance and the entirely different evolutionary path which scoring, and in our own day recording, make possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [the concept of prestige in sociolinguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_%28sociolinguistics%29):

> In sociolinguistics, prestige describes the level of respect accorded
>   to a language or dialect as compared to that of other languages or
>   dialects in a speech community. The concept of prestige in
>   sociolinguistics is closely related to that of prestige or class
>   within a society. Generally, there is positive prestige associated
>   with the language or dialect of the upper classes, and negative
>   prestige with the language or dialect of the lower classes. The
>   concept of prestige is also closely tied to the idea of the standard
>   language, in that the most prestigious dialect is likely to be
>   considered the standard language, though there are some notable
>   exceptions to this rule, such as Arabic

compare the prestige of two languages in [diglossia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia):

> refers to a situation in which two dialects or usually closely related
>   languages are used by a single language community. In addition to the
>   community's everyday or vernacular language variety (labelled "L" or
>   "low" variety), a second, highly codified variety (labelled "H" or
>   "high") is used in certain situations such as literature, formal
>   education, or other specific settings, but not used for ordinary
>   conversation.